# microsoft outlook how to send an email from an email group which I belong to?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I belong to a email group in the company I work for, such as for example, researchteam@company.com. My personal email is raulmercado@company.com. I want to send emails from researchteam@company.com instead of raulmercado@company.com. I'm using Microsoft Outlook and Exchange as a Email Server.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you using Outlook 2010 then you could try MailItem.SendUsingAccount property.
Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Exchange always sends out all emails coming from the **default** email address. And for each Exchange mailbox this default address is fixed and can not be changed in Outlook. You can use one of two options:

1. You can create an additional mailbox in Exchange for the second address (as the default email there of course) and then give your normal account "Send-As" rights for that new account. Then you can switch on the "FROM" field in Outlook (right-click options > Show Fields > From) and use that field to select the account you want to send from. In Outlook 2013 you can also just connect to the additional Exchange account and might get slighly easier switching.
2. You can use a 3rd party tool like ChangeSender (http://www.servolutions.com/changesender.htm) to get automatic switching of the accounts when you answer email (answered automatically with the account the email was received under).

Hope this helps - Claus